# Even after having the value in .csv file last column , apex is taking it as null and not able to insert that last column field in object

Tags: apex, attachment, csv

```
CsvAttach__c csv=new CsvAttach__c();
String[] fieldsData=readArray[1].split(‘,’);

For(Integer j=0;j<2 ;j++){
 if(String.isNotEmpty(fieldsData[j] &&  field[j]==‘Subject’){
csv.put(Schema.CsvAttach__c,fieldsData[j]);
}else if(String.isNotEmpty(fieldsData[j] &&  field[j]==‘Describe’){
csv.put(Schema.CsvAttach__c.Describe__c,fieldsData[j]);
}
listTobeUpdated.add(csv);
}

insert listTobeUpdated;
}
```

\no error from code side but Describe field is not getting inserted in object when I debug I got to know it is taking null value 
(‘Subject,Describe’) array is in this form

Comment: Should the first `csv.put` not also include the field token e.g. `Schema.CsvAttach__c.Subject__c`? It is hard to see what you are trying to accomplish here; it looks like perhaps store the CSV column headings if they match specific words, but the headings row would more likely be `readArray[0].split(‘,’);`.

Comment: yes String[] field=readArray[0].split(‘,’);
which consists first row of the Attachment and i m comparing with static value.

Comment: yes first csv.put (Schema.CsvAttach__c.Subject__c,fieldsData[j])

Comment: This code is rather confusing, and there's not enough information here to find a solution. I recommend (1) editing the code to use static field references instead of `put()` calls, use proper indentation; naming `listToBeUpdated` `listToBeInserted` instead. None of those things are the problem as such but they make what should be very simple code hard to read. And (2), please provide a complete, reproducible example of the problem, including CSV data and all of the code that parses it.